# Foreach() isn't cycling through the arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

Basically I have a `file_get_contents` that gets json, then I decode the json. My problem is using `Foreach()` to cycler through all the arrays, it doesn't seem to be doing it, I've made sure the arrays aren't empty by using `print_r()`. This script is pretty similar to one I have that works fine, but for some reason this one doesn't work.

```
foreach($items['item'] as $ind=>$d2){                   
      $id = $d2['id'];
}
```

That is my code, I really have no idea why it isn't working.

PS. I tried doing

```
$i = 0; 
foreach($items[$i] as $ind=>$d2){
        $id = $d2['id'];
        $i++;
}
```

And that only got to the 9th array before stopping without error.

Thanks,

Archey

Comment: Post JSON that is decoded into $items please.

Comment: Can you please post the value of `$items['item']`?

Comment: You are presumably aware that that code doesn't *do* anything? Assigning the same variable over and over in a loop achieves nothing other than setting that variable to the last value. It's usually a good idea to show example input and current/desired output with questions like this.

Comment: Instead of print_r, use var_dump to see the datatype of your elements as well. If they are of type stdClass, then you need to work with them differently than you would if they are just an array.

Comment: @DaveRandom I'm aware of that, this is my desired output, for now. I will later be using an if statement. Thanks to Daan's post it works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($items as $ind=>$d2){
        $id = $d2['id'];
}
```

Could you try this one ?
I don't think you need to fill in that key.

http://php.net/foreach

Comment: Thanks! This worked, not sure why since in my other script im using `$items['item']`

Answer (score 0):

json_decode probably returns u a stdClass and not array

Comment: Why would you assume that?  It doesn't, by the way. [json_decode](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I have to assume, until u post the code, what do u json_decode and bellow

Comment: You can force it to return an associative array instead of objects of type stdClass, but by default, if you pass it a json object (or array of json_objects) you will get stdClass objects when you decode.